# Test if both numbers are positive or negative in Python

Tags: python

I am comparing lists of numbers and assigning "scores" for matching direction. Each match positive or negative should increase the participant's score by 1.

For example:

```
list1 =[5.6, -7.1, 6.4]
list2 =[4.5, -2.0, -4.2]
```

should give a score of 2 for the participant, because 5.6 and 4.5 are both positive (+1) and -7.1 and -2.0 are both negative (+1).

I have it working fine for comparing positives:

```
def score2(list1, list2):
    count = 0
    for index in range (0, len(list1)):
        if list1[index] and list2[index] > 0:
            count += 1
        return count
```

But the section for negatives kept returning 0 even though -7.1 and -2.0 are both negative. I had it as an `elif` section in the previous function before, but I separated it to debug:

```
def score3(list1, list2):
    count = 0
    for index in range (0, len(list1)):
        if list1[index] and list2[index] < 0:
            count += 1
        return count
```

The funny thing is, if I do

```
print list1[1] and list2[1] < 0
```

it does print `True`. So I'm not sure what's wrong in `score3`.

Answer (score 3):

`list1[index] and list2[index] < 0` means `list1[index] and (list2[index] < 0)`.  The `and` applies to `list1[index]` and the *result* of `list2[index] < 0`.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) to understand how `and` and `or` work.  What you want is:

```
list1[index] < 0 and list2[index] < 0
```

The same is happening in your first example testing for positives, but you're not noticing it because it happens to work.  For that case, you should likewise do:

```
list1[index] > 0 and list2[index] > 0
```

Comment: The grouping goes the other way: `list1[index] and (list2[index] < 0)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can score this very easily:

```
result = sum(x*y > 0 for x, y in zip(list1, list2))
```

How does it work?

`zip()` pairs corresponding elements in tuples: `(5.6, 4.5), (-7.1, -2.0), (6.4, -4.2)`

You can iterate over those tuples with generator expression and multiply both numbers. If both numbers are negative or both numbers are positive, you product will be greater than zero. Thus expression `x*y > 0` evaluates to `True` if both number have the same sign.

Serie of `True/False` values is then summed by builtin `sum()`, where `True` counts as `1` and False as `0`. Giving you score you wanted.

PS. This solution is faster than using ifs. Float multiplication is ~4 cycles on modern hardware and all computations are linear, without any conditional jumps, allowing for heavy optimization, like pipelining.

*EDIT*

Now, what was wrong with your `score3()`.

Boolean operator `and / or` work lazily, returning first value that makes result of expression known. In case of `and` this is first value that evaluates to `False` (can be empty string, 0, empty list, None etc.) or the last value, if all were 'trueish'.

So in your case, expression was evaluated (for index 1) like:

```
-7.1 and -2.0 < 0
```

-7.1 is non-zero value, so it is True. Expression must be evaluated further. -2.0 is also `True` so `(-7.1 and -2.0)` evaluates to **`-2.0`**. Now, this value is compared with 0: `-2.0 < 0`, which is `True`.

I hope that clears it up for you. ;)

Comment: +1 for the `x*y > 0` (and the rest, which is neat too) ...even though it doesn't specifically answer the  original question of "what's wrong in score3".  (Does `True` really evaluate to 1?  I had forgotten...)

Comment: @aldo good point, I've added explanation for `and` operator workings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip and sum with list comprehension:

```
sum([1 for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2) if ((l1>=0 and l2 >=0) or (l1<0 and l2 < 0)) ])
```

Comment: Couldn't the `if` be simplified with `if l1*l2 > 0`?

Comment: Multiplications are costlier than simple boolean checks.

Comment: @SukritKalra actually multiplication is faster than this solution (3:5 ratio for 1M long lists)

Comment: You didn't match your parentheses and brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
list1[1] and list2[1] < 0
```

tests whether `list1[1]` is nonzero AND `list2[1]` is less than zero.

```
list1[1] > 0 and list2[1] > 0
```

tests whether `list1[1]` is greater than zero AND `list2[1]` is greater than zero.

Comment: According to the [language reference](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `and` has higher precedence than `<`, so I think your analysis is incorrect.

Comment: @SamMussmann: You're reading it backwards. The table goes from lowest precedence to highest.

Comment: @AdamSmith `-2 and 3` evaluates to `3`. `3 and -2` evaluates to `-2`