# How to improve this pattern of checking if two numbers are both positive or negative?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I find myself creating this pattern alot:

```
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    if _x > 0 and _y > 0:
        something += 1
    elif _x < 0 and _y < 0:
        something += 1
    else:
        something -= 1
```

and I just feel that there must be a pythonic way that's better than that. It's such a simple algorithm that it just feels like a waste of time typing all that out.

So, how would I improve that?

Edit: Regarding the duplicate question thingy, this is not related to that. This is not a question on how I would go about creating the wanted logic, that logic is already in my question. What I'm asking is how to improve on the pattern I'm using.

Comment: You can try combining the first 2 conditions into 1 condition by using a OR condition.

Comment: @SomyaAvasthi So something like `if (_x > 0 and _y > 0) or (_x < 0 and _y < 0)` ?

Comment: Yes, since when either of both conditions are true ,you are doing the same operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if both numbers are positive or negative in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770274/test-if-both-numbers-are-positive-or-negative-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only improvement I can think of:

```
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    something += 1 if _x * _y > 0 else -1
```

Comment: How is cramming all the logic into one line an improvement?

Comment: That's brilliant, nifty way of using multiplication. So that's basically Pythons way of using ternary operators?

Comment: @wim Well to be fair my issue is that the logic is so simple that it should be one line instead of 6 lines.

Comment: or `int(x < 0) ==  int(y < 0)` avoids the slight cost of the multiply. I don't know if @kakeuno cares but we are all ignoring changes of behaviour when x==0 or y==0

Comment: In my opinion it is really *not* that simple that it should be 1 line.  I would want to see test coverage for all three different branches in the coverage report here, which somewhat vindicates the 6 lines of code as originally presented.

Comment: @wim Totally get what you're saying. It's just that I end up using that pattern alot in non-production code and it's such a trivial task that 6 lines feel unnecessary.

Comment: Multiplication is the better solution as it preserves the original x==0 or y==0 behaviour (1 is subtracted), and I can't imagine a modern CPU on which casting two bools to ints costs less than a multiply.

Comment: @GemTaylor Good idea, it also works without the `int` call: `(_x > 0) == (_y > 0)`

Comment: @fafi yes the cast is just for pylint, and for human clarity. Most folk don't expect to see you do an `not xor` as an `==`

Answer (score 1):

```
for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
    if _x * _y > 0:
        something += 1
     else:
        something -= 1
```

Comment: Wait, what the hell is going on in the second snippet? Could you walk me through it?

Comment: Although now I've seen it I prefer fafl's answer :)

Comment: Sure: (_x * _y) > 0 is a bool, which when cast to an int becomes 0 or 1, which is then used to index an array containing -1 and 1

Comment: I would consider it lt less clear than fafl's, so I'm going to delete it as it's not good advice.

Comment: Please keep it, I hate how it looks but it's a cool way of solving the problem. That solution would never have crossed my mind!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your code is already good as it is, and does not need improvement:

- Is readable
- Is clear
- Works as it should
- Is fast

Anyway, if you want to reduce the [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity), you may externalize the if conditions:

```
def evaluate_zipped(x,y):
    if (x > 0 and y > 0) or (x < 0 and y < 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

for _x, _y in zip(x,y):
    something += evaluate_zipped(_x, _y)
```

If you're looking for a one-liner, you can `map` your decision statements:

```
something += sum(map(lambda _x,_y: 1 if _x*_y > 0 else -1, x,y))
```

I'd anyway advise avoiding one-liners since you lose readability and gain nothing in return.